# What are the min-width bootstrap uses?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What are the different minimum width bootstrap uses for its layouts? I see 480px, 768px, 992px, 1200px. Are there any others?

Comment: Are you talking about media query min-width?

Comment: yes. `@media (min-width: 480px)`

Comment: Then take look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I know how they work, I was asking which break points does bootstrap use.

Comment: This site is full of trolls now who vote down everything though. I cannot even post questions on here anymore...

Answer (score 0):

[here is a link for bootstrap 3 grid breakdown](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)